# How to pipe removed filenames to file?

Tags: linux

I am using this command:
`find /var/mydirectory/foo -mmin +720 -exec rm {} \;`

Can I make it log the filenames removed to a log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`tee`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)) command in conjunction with [`xargs`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs).

```
find /var/mydirectory/foo -mmin +720 | tee files.log | xargs rm
```

Answer (score 4):

You could always use the `--verbose` option to `rm`, unless you want just the literal filenames by themselves.

Comment: I like this answer... if something goes wrong with unlinking, none of the other methods will reflect that.

Comment: In this case I actually just want the filenames to compare against another log for an issue I'm having.

Comment: @DaveStein You could always `sed`/`grep` out the filenames from the output of `rm -v` if you're really concerned that something may have gone wrong and want to make *absolutely* sure you're only dealing with the files that were deleted.  However, that's likely unnecessary and it would be somewhat unclear.  The solution with `tee` will be extremely clear to anybody familiar with the shell.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
find /var/mydirectory/foo -mmin +720 | tee file.txt | xargs rm
```

Comment: Not whitespace-safe

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
find /var/mydirectory/foo -mmin +720 > file.txt
rm $(< file.txt)
```